# How to populate a form containing fields related to a "nested" resource from an URL request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to populate a form from an URL request. That is, by using a URL as-like (the following is just an - *wrong* - example) `http://website.com/query?user[account_attributes][firstname]=Sample Name` I would like to populate a form field in the requested web page with the `user[account_attributes][firstname]` data.

My issue is related to

- using Ruby on Rails "nested" models;
- having the following output code related to the field that I would like to "auto"-populate by using the URL query string data;

  < input type="text" name="user[account_attributes][firstname]">

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok didn't understand the question first. You need to have accepts_nested_attributes for set for account_attributes.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Then in the new method of the controller you need to populate your model:

User.new(params[:account_attributes])

Comment: I would like to accomplish what I wrote in the question considering the following "scenario": *the HTTP request is redirected* (thus, the related URL data is redirected - I am not sure about this) *from a web site to "another"* and in that request there is the data with which I'd populate the form on the "another" website. The point is: *how can I handle that data in the described "scenario"?*